# Obtain reference to View in ActionScript class within ViewNavigatorApplication

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I've got a very simple project in FlashBuilder 4.5. It's a mobile application of type ViewNavigatorApplication with a single view, MapView. In the MapView.mxml file, I've got a Flex component of type Map declared in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" name="CatBusMapView">

    <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import com.esri.ags.Map;
                        ....
                    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
     ....
    </fx:Declarations>

    <esri:Map id="cbm">
        ...
    </esri:Map>
</s:View>
```

In this same project, I've an actionscript class called UserGeolocation. In this class, I'm attempting to get a reference to this map component.

So far, I can get a reference to the top-level application, its ViewNavigator and the NavigationStack of said ViewNavigator. However, I cannot find a way to access the MapView, much less the map I've declared within it.

I'm aware of methods like firstView() and activeView(), but I want an absolute solution, one that retrieves the view regardless of whether or not it's first or active. I've tried navigator.getChildByName("MapView") with no luck.

Comment: Try dependency injection.  In other words, make a property on your UserGeolocation Class that can accept a reference to the view and set that property to the View instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Amy. I've never used dependency injection outside of the context of a fully formed framework (Spring) and don't really require such a framework for this application. Could you elaborate on what you have in mind?

Comment: Don't be ridiculous.  Of course you have.  Any time that you have set a property on a component, or provided an argument to a constructor, you've used dependency injection.  If you create a getter/setter pair on your UserGeoLocation Class and actually set that value to the instance of the view, Viola! you have used dependency injection to resolve the problem.

Comment: How would I go about retrieving the instance of the UserGeoLocation class that has been "injected"? Recall that my initial intent was to refer to the View in the UserGeolocation class. If I were to instantiate and inject it elsewhere, how would that instance then be available to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to underscore the original intent of the question: I want an absolute reference to a View in a ViewNavigatorApplication. I'm surprised there's no clear way of doing this in the API, since it seems common practice to put Flex components in Views, in the form of declarative MXML. Existing methods that manipulate the stack aren't helpful in this regard, because they are either a) conditional upon the active or first view, or b) affect the visual presentation of the application.

There are three general solutions that have been suggested which, oddly enough, focus on problems engendered by multiple stacks in TabbedViewNavigatorApplication and don't mention the ViewNavigatorApplication.

- Put the object/component you want access to at the [top of the container hierarchy](http://devgirl.org/2011/08/09/flex-mobile-development-passing-data-between-tabs-part-1-includes-source/) (ie FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication)
- [Use a lightweight framework](http://devgirl.org/2011/08/09/flex-mobile-development-passing-data-between-tabs-part-2-includes-source/)
- Use events (either [custom](http://riaconnection.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/passing-data-between-viewnavigators-in-flash-builder-4-5-burrito/) or [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324164/148680))

I opted for the first.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it using events. Fire a custom event from the MapView onActivate/creationComplete, and pass the esri map component cbm as the data part of the event.

Have a listener in the main ViewNavigatorApplication class that listens for this event. In the handler of the event listener, you can access this through event.data, and then assign it to a variable declared in the main class or in the UserGeolocation class.

Brian

Comment: +1 because you didn't leave me with "Amy's answer is correct."